# Video Editing API Suggestions?

Tags: c#, directx, directshow, ms-media-foundation, video-editing

I have a specific requirement of being able to select arbitrary rectangular regions from a source video and to save that region (for a specific time span) to a separate file.

Ideally, the API would support C#/.NET but we're prepared to do it in C++ if that would yield a better end product.

This software will need to run on Windows machines.

I've looked into Direct Show Editing Services and Media Foundation.  I've found conflicting information that says DSES is deprecated, but then to use DSES over MF because MF doesn't focus on video editing that much.

Are there are any other APIs that I should look into?
Can you recommend either of the mentioned APIs for the task at hand?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't actually looked into it for your scenario but power point 2013+ has a fairly powerful screen recorder including both video and audio. You can definitely select arbitrary regions of the screen and save to different files.... just not simultaneously. Not sure if you can access these features via the Office API but might be worth a quick look.depending on need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For video editing in Windows desktop apps, DirectShow remains really the only Windows API for this scenario. See [Migrating from DirectShow to Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468614.aspx)

For C#, take a look at [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

> DirectShow is not supported for Windows Store, universal Windows apps, Xbox One, or Windows phone 8.

Also keep in mind that DirectShow is impacted by the "N" editions of Windows. See ["Who moved my [Windows Media] Cheese"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/08/13/quot-who-moved-my-windows-media-cheese-quot.aspx)

Comment: Are you able to confirm that DirectShow can definitely handle the specific task outlined (i.e. splitting a video into visual regions and saving each region as a separate file)?

Comment: DirectShow can provide a Direct3D 9 2D texture which can you do your own processing on like this.

Comment: The article is from 2006. Media Foundation has advanced since then.

Comment: @Gusdor: Sure, but the docs haven't :)